# How to check if a value doesn't exist in one or more arrays inside array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to write a function that returns true if a value exists in a multidimensional array and false if the value doesn't exist in atleast one array in the multidimensional array.

```
    function isItemOmnipresent (arrayOfArrays, item) {

     var arrays = arrayOfArrays;
     var itemCheck = item;

     for(var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++){
       if(arrays[i][j] == itemCheck) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You `return false` too soon. Move that statement after the nested loop.

Comment: Your code would work if you would exchange `==` and `===` and the thing above

Comment: I've put the return false statement outside the nested loop and the == with === but still doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function like this one - see this https://jsfiddle.net/jde2urL6/:

```
    function isValuePresent(arr, value) {
  var result = false;

  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
        result = isValuePresent(arr[i], value);
      }
      else {
        if (arr[i] === value)
          result = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

As the for loop iterates over each array element in the array it checks to see if that item is an (nested) array and if so the method calls back into itself (recursive) to check if any of the elements within the nested array have a matching value. If the element is not an array the value of that element is checked against the desired "to find" value - if so it sets result to true. I added a "visual" below (the flow starts at the first red horizontal line). I hope that brings a little more clarification.

[image]

Comment: better to return as soon as match found...no need to keep iterating beyond that

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more what you did here?

Answer (score 1):

```
 const check = (multi, value) => multi.some(array => array.includes(value));
```

Usable like this:

```
check([[1,2],[3,4]], 2);
```

Comment: This is nice! I didn't think to combo `includes` and `some`

Answer (score 0):

Much like *"There's an App for that!"* - typically *"There's a Method for that!"* if you look hard enough and this is the case for your issue. You can use the `.some` method of an Array to determine if anything within meets the required value.

We set a flag called `inArrays` to keep track if the returned value of the `some` function is ever true and return it at the end of our function call.

```
function isItemPresent(OuterArr, item) {
  let inArrays = false;

  for (let InnerArr of OuterArr) {
    if(InnerArr.some(array_item => array_item === item)) {
    inArrays = true;
    }
  }
  return inArrays;
}
```

```js
let _2dArr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [6, 7, 8, 9]
];


function isItemPresent(OuterArr, item) {
  let inArrays = false;

  for (let InnerArr of OuterArr) {
    if(InnerArr.some(array_item => array_item === item)) {
    inArrays = true;
    }
  }
  return inArrays;
}

console.log(isItemPresent(_2dArr, 3));
console.log(isItemPresent(_2dArr, 5));
```

**ES5/IE**

Here's an IE/ES5 Friendly Version if you're worried about that sort of thing

```
function isItemPresent(OuterArr, item) {
  var inArrays = false;

  for (InnerArr = 0; InnerArr < OuterArr.length; InnerArr++) {
    if(OuterArr[InnerArr].some(function(array_item) { return array_item === item; })) {
    inArrays = true;
    }
  }
  return inArrays;
}
```

```js
var _2dArr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [6, 7, 8, 9]
];


function isItemPresent(OuterArr, item) {
  var inArrays = false;

  for (InnerArr = 0; InnerArr < OuterArr.length; InnerArr++) {
    if(OuterArr[InnerArr].some(function(array_item) { return array_item === item; })) {
    inArrays = true;
    }
  }
  return inArrays;
}

console.log(isItemPresent(_2dArr, 3));
console.log(isItemPresent(_2dArr, 5));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this brings clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two clear, efficient approaches:

```
// using a simple for-iterator
function IsItemOmnipresent(arrayOfArrays, item, present = false) {  
  for (const e of arrayOfArrays) {
    if (typeof e === 'object' && e.length) {
      return IsItemOmnipresent(e, item, present);
    }
    else {
        present = e === item;
    }
  }

  return present;
}

// using .reduce()
function IsItemOmnipresent(arrayOfArrays, item) {
  let isPresent = function (present, e) {
    if (typeof e === 'object' && e.length) {
      return IsItemOmnipresent(e, item);
    }
    else {
      present = e === item;
    }

    return present;
  };

  return arrayOfArrays.reduce(isPresent, false);  
}

console.log(IsItemOmnipresent([[1, 1], [1, 3], [5, 1], [6, 1]], 1)) //true
console.log(IsItemOmnipresent([[1, 1], [1, 3], [5, 1], [6, 1]], 6)) // false
console.log(IsItemOmnipresent([[5], [5], [5], [6, 5]], 5)) // true
console.log(IsItemOmnipresent([[5], [5], [5], [6, 5]], 6)) // false
console.log(IsItemOmnipresent([[5, 1], [5, 1], [5, 1], [6, 5, 1]], 1)) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isOmnipre(arr, val) {
    let newarr = []
    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i][1] !== val && arr[i][0] !== val){
            newarr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    } 
    //return newarr;
    if(newarr.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
console.log(isOmnipre([[5], [5], [5], [6, 5]], 6))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use function like this.

```
    function isOmnipresent(arr, val) {
     return arr.every(ar=>ar.includes(val));
}
```

Comment: This does not provides an answer to the question, this code will check if each element from the passed array includes the specified value, OP asked for how to check if a specific value is not present in nested arrays (in multiple levels of depth)

Comment: If specified value is not present, it will return false.

Comment: It will return false if **at least one element of `arr` is not `val`**, `every` verifies if all elements of the given array are exactly the same